check_ping in nagios resolves to ipv6 instead of ipv4
mn1.testchn1s1.ind ~# /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_ping -H mn1.testchn1s1.pub -w "700,60%" -c "1400,100%" -p 5 -4 -s
PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.10 ms - mn1.testchn1s1.pub(3a00:82c0:2211:15::4) ()|rta=0.098000ms;700.000000;1400.000000;0.000000 pl=0%;60;100;0

mn1.testchn1s1.ind ~# ping mn1.testchn1s1.pub -4
PING mn1.testchn1s1.pub (10.221.15.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from mn1.testchn1s1.pub (10.221.15.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- mn1.testchn1s1.pub ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.037/0.037/0.037/0.000 ms

Above the check_ping resolves the hostname to ipv6 address with -4 option. Though the ping the same hostname resolves to ipv4 with -4 option. I would need help in resolving why it is resolved to ipv6 even after with -4 option'

if ipv6 is diswanted at all disable it on OS level

it has dual ip address, we need both ipv4 and ipv6. It returns ipv6 address when we run check_ping with -6 as expected

https://support.nagios.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47671 seems to speak about a similar situation. try to move -4 to the last point. should not matter but give it a try
